# C project with Mysql

Tags: mysql, c, xcode

I am writing a C project in Xcode 5 (out of curiosity.) If I remember correctly, C can interact with databases, right?
I started to read this tutorial http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-connect-mysql-c-api-program.html
But I know that there is no mysql lib available, by default. 
So I went to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/ and downloaded the mysql-connector-c-6.1.3-osx10.7-x86.tar.gz. After that, I added the includes folder and the libs folder to my project.
The error that I encountered was : 'mysql/plugin_auth_common.h' file not found

I am really not finding a good tutorial to learn how to write C projects in Xcode, that too connect with mysql databases.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Is the path with the mysql/plugin_auth_common.h included in your include environment variable?

Comment: Yep, added the mysql folder in library search paths

Comment: You added the mysql folder, or the path that it's in. If you have a file in /path/to/directory/file.h  and have /path/to/directory in your include path, then refer to "/directory/file.h" you're not going to find the library.  If you've actually included the mysql folder, try just including plugin_auth_common.h.